# How to get my output in center of the level in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I have just made a very small project using javaFX using netbins IDE where user will get some random numbers. This is my output:

[image: my output]

My problem is :

1. The numbers are shown in left aligned in the level.How can i get them in the center of the level?
2. Can I fix the size of the full output screen which can not be changeable by user ?

My code :

**GenerateRandomNumber.java**

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package generaterandomnumber;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author USER
 */
public class GenerateRandomNumber extends Application {

    private Stage stage;
    private double decorationWidth;
    private double decorationHeight;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        this.stage = stage;
        final double initialSceneWidth = 500;
        final double initialSceneHeight = 300;

        final Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, initialSceneWidth, initialSceneHeight);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("main.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setTitle("Generating Random Numbers");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        this.decorationWidth = initialSceneWidth - scene.getWidth();
        this.decorationHeight = initialSceneHeight - scene.getHeight();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**main.fxml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="500.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" fx:controller="generaterandomnumber.MainController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@main.css" />
    </stylesheets>
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="Clickme" layoutX="209.0" layoutY="182.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#generateRandom" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="85.0" text="Click me" />
      <Label fx:id="myMessage" layoutX="139.0" layoutY="53.0" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="220.0" />
      <Button fx:id="Exit" layoutX="226.0" layoutY="228.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#exit" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="50.0" text="Exit" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**main.css**

```
.mainFxmlClass {

}
#Clickme{
    -fx-font-size: 15px;
    -fx-background-color: blue;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-padding: 6 6 6 6;
    -fx-border-radius: 8;
    -fx-fill-width: bold;
}
#Exit{
     -fx-font-size: 15px;
     -fx-background-color: blueviolet;
     -fx-text-fill: white;
     -fx-fill-width: bold;
}
#myMessage{
    -fx-font-size: 25px;
    -fx-background-color:wheat;
    -fx-text-fill: purple;
    -fx-padding: 6 6 6 6;
    -fx-border-radius: 8;
    -fx-fill-width: bold;
    -fx-text-alignment: center;
}
.root{
    -fx-background-color:whitesmoke;
}
```

**MainController.java**

```
package generaterandomnumber;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class MainController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Label myMessage;
    public void generateRandom(ActionEvent event){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int myrand = rand.nextInt(50)+1;
        myMessage.setText(Integer.toString(myrand));
    }
    public void exit(ActionEvent event){
        System.exit(0);
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

Comment: see http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/TextAlignmentJUSTIFY.htm

Comment: For your second question: "Can I fix the size of the full output screen which can not be changeable by user?", it's a bit ambiguous, you might mean [`stage.setFullScreen(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setFullScreen-boolean-) but probably you mean [`stage.setResizable(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setResizable-boolean-).

Answer (score 2):

To position a generated number in the centre you have to add **alignment="CENTER"** to the *Label* element:

```
<Label fx:id="myMessage" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="139.0" layoutY="53.0" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="220.0">
```

[image]

To fix the window size add to the *GenerateRandomNumber.start()* method:

```
primaryStage.setResizable(false);
```

[setResizable()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setResizable-boolean-) method allows to set the value of the property [resizable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#resizableProperty)

Comment: How did you code for this  something different designed window (like border less + a different color & some different buttons in the title bar "Generating Random Number") from my provided window??

Comment: This is a native look and feel which JavaFX provides automatically (Ubuntu in my case), see here for examples: http://fxexperience.com/2013/01/modena-new-theme-for-javafx-8/

Comment: If you look at the link @Boris provided, the picture on the top left looks to be Mac based, the top right Linux based, the bottom left Windows based, and the bottom right I am not sure. I will guess the bottom right is an older version of Windows.

Comment: FWIW, bottom left is Windows Aero, (which is discontinued) and bottom right is Windows Metro (which is the current design language for Windows).